# is it possible to have radio button for parent and checkbox button for children in jstree?

Tags: javascript, jstree

I want the parent nodes to act like radio buttons but all its child nodes to be checkbox buttons, using "multiple: true" alone is not enough, what i want is by clicking/checking one of parent node, all other parent nodes should be unchecked, see the following codes, hope someone can help me figure out the solution, thanks.

```
.on('changed.jstree', async (e, data) => {
const node = data.instance.get_node(data.node, true); // current clicked and checked parent checkbox
let siblings = node.siblings('li[aria-level="1"]'); // all other parent checkboxs
for (let i = 0; i < siblings.length; i++) {
    let sibling = siblings[i];
    sibling.ariaSelected = false; // all other parent checkboxs should be unchecked, that's my objective!
    $.jstree.reference('#').refresh(sibling); // try to reflect change in UI but not working
}
$.jstree.reference('#').redraw(true); // try to reflect changes in UI but not working
});
```

Comment: this is rather a question of jstree, instead of Autodesk Forge. I would suggest you also tag jstree community to have attention of the gurus of jstree.  In my practice, I only played with checkbox or radio only.

Comment: thanks Xiaodong, i tried searching jstree but no solution yet, from your JS experience w/ checkbox, what is the proper way to uncheck all other checkboxes after clicking one checkbox, i understand it's not Forge related so you can ignore my question.

Comment: figured out, need to have separate event of select_node.jstree

Comment: @bim2016 can you please share your code because I am also trying to do something similar

Comment: i believe i added the event like .on("select_node.jstree", async (e, data) => {}), i need to dig my old code as i'm currently not on Forge